# Populating NSDictionary with values from an XML parser

Tags: iphone, objective-c

My hobby project is getting over my head! I am using an XML parser, which gives me a set of values
row.blurb
row.url
row.keywords
etc.

I now need to put them into an NSDictionary to populate a table, but my understanding of dictionaries is letting me down. I was expecting to be able to say something like

```
[exhibitors addObject:[[NSMutableDictionary alloc]initWithObjectsAndKeys:
[row.blurb],@"blurb",[row.url],@"url",[row.keywords],"keywords",nil]];
```

But, as none of you will be at all surprised, I get a crash. Can anyone help me with the correct way to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are providing a `C` string as one of the keys -> `"keywords"`.

That is not a valid key in an `NSDictionary` instance. You probably intended it to be `@"keywords"`.

To add, you are also leaking memory as you are creating an object but aren't releasing it as you don't have a reference. You can use the convenience method `dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys :` to create an autoreleased instance so that you don't leak.

```
[exhibitors addObject:[NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:row.blurb, @"blurb", row.url, @"url", row.keywords, @"keywords", nil]];
```

Comment: Yes, but that's just a typo here. It's correct in my code, so not the error.

Comment: Are you sure the code is compiling? The dot syntax shouldn't be paired with the square brackets. And can you verify if they all have valid values? Try logging them.

Comment: I'm a fool. You're both right - there was an invalid key in there. And I was getting confused with the various things I'd tried to fix it - one of which was using the square brackets, which of course doesn't compile. Thanks for your time.